# PHP Object Question

Tags: php, oop

Unfortunately I cannot provide any code examples, however I will try and create an example.
My question is about Objects and memory allocation in PHP.

If I have an object, lets say:

```
$object = new Class();
```

Then I do something like

```
$object2 = $object;
```

What is this actualy doing? I know there is a clone function, but thats not what I'm asking about, I'm concerned about whether this is creating another identical object, or if its just assigning a reference to $object.

I strongly understand this to mean that it just creates a reference, but in some case usages of mine, I find that I get another $object created, and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the magic method `__invoke`, you can call an object similar to a function, and it will call that magic method.

```
class Object{
    function __invoke(){ return "hi"; }
}

$object = new Object;
$object2 = $object();
echo $object2; // echos hi
```

That means that `$object2` is equal to whatever that function returns.

Basically, you are calling a function, but using a variable as it's name. So:

```
function test(){ echo "hi"; }
$function_name = "test";
$function_name(); // echos hi.
```

In this case, you are just calling an object instead.

So, in reference to your question, this is actually not 'cloning' at all, unless the `__invoke()` function looks like this:

```
function __invoke(){ return this }
```

In which case, it would be a reference to the same class.

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not understand the relevance? Can you explain.

Comment: @Laykes, your code has a parentheses around the assignment, so Chacha102 assumed you were asking how to use the invoke handler in PHP.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide how this might be used for reference assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a second reference of the same object. Here is a proof:

```
<?php
class TestClass {
    private $number;

    function __construct($num) { $this->number = $num; }
    function increment() { $this->number++; }

    function __toString() { return (string) $this->number; }
}

$original = new TestClass(10);

echo "Testing =\n";
echo "--------------------------------\n";
echo '$equal = $original;' . "\n";
$equal = $original;

echo '$equal = ' . $equal . ";\n";

echo '$original->increment();' . "\n";
$original->increment();

echo '$equal = ' . $equal . ";\n";

echo "\n";
echo "Testing clone\n";
echo "--------------------------------\n";
echo '$clone = clone $original;' . "\n";
$clone = clone $original;

echo '$clone = ' . $clone . ";\n";

echo '$original->increment();' . "\n";
$original->increment();

echo '$clone = ' . $clone . ";\n";
```

Use [`clone`](http://php.net/oop5.cloning) if you want to create a copy of an instance.

Comment: Well, you didn't exactly answer the question, which was: What is `$object2 = $object()` doing. In fact, none of you did.

Comment: Also, I didn't down vote until after I got the accepted answer, as I wanted to make sure he didn't mistype the `$object()`. But it turns out that he didn't. And none of you actually addressed that.

Comment: So, I'd like to say that your comment insinuating me for stratgetically downvoting is insulting and completely false.

Comment: @Chacha102: I wasn't necessarily aiming at you. I miss read the question. With all that talk of `clone` and references, it was hard to miss the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean

```
$object2 = $object;
```

And not

```
$object2 = $object();
```

PHP will create a reference to the original object, it will not copy it. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php, the section called 
Object Assignment.

Comment: I did mean the first, but the first poster answered another question I have had in the past. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Object{
    public $value = 1;

    public function inc(){
        $this->value++;
    }
}

$object = new Object;
$object2 = $object;

$object->inc();

echo $object2->value; // echos 2, proving it's by reference
```